# Will this while loop end when the if statement inside is met

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this block of function that searches through my email column for matches. After a match has been found, will this While loop continue to search for other matches or will it end if the if statement inside it is met?

```
function find_similar_email ($email) {
    global $con;
    // select db
    mysql_select_db('practice', $con);

    // select a column to search from
    $emailList = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users", $con);

    // search for similar matches
    while ($emailListResult = mysql_fetch_array($emailList)) {
        if ($email == $emailListResult['email']) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. I'd recommend running `return false` afterwards. Also, `mysqli_`, and DI, (pass `$con` to `find_similar_email`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the if conditon is met, the return statement will be exectued. This leaves the function, and effectively ends the while loop.

Comment: Thank you, now I know return ends it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `return` will exit the function, effectively terminating the loop.

However, you should use a `WHERE` clause to do your selection rather than selecting everything and searching the result. Since you're only looking to see if the email address is in the table you could do this:

```
function find_similar_email ($email) {
  global $con;
  // select db
  mysql_select_db('practice', $con);

  // select all rows with matching email address
  $emailList = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users where `email`='$email'", $con) or die(mysql_error($con); 

  return(mysql_num_rows($emailList) !== 0);  // return true if we found it, false if we didn't
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"return" exits the function. so yes, no more rows will be read...